# Error in running glinternet : a statistical function for automatic model selection using interaction terms by Stanford's professor T. Hastie

Tags: r, classification, logistic-regression, glmnet

The glinternet is an R package and a function that implements an algorithm developed by Trevor Hastie -- the eminent Stanford professor on Statistical Learning -- and his ex-phD student.  `glinternet()` detects automatically interaction terms and as such it is very useful in building a model in a situation with many variables where the possible combinations are enormous.

When I run `glinternet` I get an error message which I reproduce here using the `mtcars` base R dataset:

```
data(mtcars)
setDT(mtcars)
glimpse(mtcars)
x = as.matrix(mtcars[, -c("am"), with = FALSE])
class(x)
y <- mtcars$am
class(y)

glinter_fit <- glinternet(x , y, numLevels = 2)
Error: pCat + pCont == ncol(X) is not TRUE
```

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: The help for `glinternet` says `numLevels` is the "Number of levels for each variable, of length nvars. Set to 1 for continuous variables." So it should be a vector with 10 integers, giving the number of levels for each of the 10 columns in `x`.

Comment: @eipi10, this was not really clear from the doc nor reading the code, though a close read with your interpretation in mind, `glinternet` is now churning away. The code starts looking like dim check, then goes to assignment of continuous or categorical, and the vector is used to make that split so all makes sense. thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear, but you need to provide a vector that is as long as your number of predictor columns, each element indicating the number of categories for each column.

In your example, in `x` it's all continuous, so we do:

```
glinternet(x,y,numLevels=rep(1,ncol(x)))

Call: glinternet(X = x, Y = y, numLevels = rep(1, ncol(x)))
     lambda objValue cat cont catcat contcont catcont
1  0.068900   0.1210   0    0      0        0       0
2  0.062800   0.1200   0    1      0        0       0
3  0.057100   0.1180   0    1      0        0       0
4  0.052000   0.1160   0    1      0        0       0
5  0.047300   0.1130   0    2      0        0       0
6  0.043100   0.1100   0    2      0        0       0
7  0.039200   0.1060   0    3      0        0       0
8  0.035700   0.1020   0    3      0        0       0
9  0.032500   0.0983   0    3      0        0       0
10 0.029600   0.0944   0    3      0        0       0
11 0.026900   0.0904   0    3      0        0       0
12 0.024500   0.0866   0    3      0        0       0
13 0.022300   0.0829   0    3      0        0       0
14 0.020300   0.0794   0    3      0        0       0
15 0.018500   0.0760   0    3      0        0       0
16 0.016800   0.0728   0    3      0        1       0
17 0.015300   0.0698   0    4      0        1       0
18 0.014000   0.0668   0    4      0        1       0
19 0.012700   0.0638   0    4      0        2       0
20 0.011600   0.0608   0    4      0        2       0
21 0.010500   0.0579   0    3      0        2       0
22 0.009580   0.0551   0    3      0        2       0
23 0.008720   0.0523   0    3      0        2       0
24 0.007940   0.0497   0    3      0        2       0
25 0.007230   0.0472   0    3      0        3       0
26 0.006580   0.0448   0    5      0        3       0
27 0.005990   0.0425   0    5      0        3       0
28 0.005450   0.0403   0    5      0        3       0
29 0.004960   0.0382   0    5      0        3       0
30 0.004520   0.0361   0    4      0        3       0
31 0.004110   0.0342   0    4      0        3       0
32 0.003740   0.0324   0    4      0        4       0
33 0.003410   0.0307   0    4      0        5       0
34 0.003100   0.0291   0    4      0        6       0
35 0.002820   0.0275   0    3      0        6       0
36 0.002570   0.0261   0    3      0        6       0
37 0.002340   0.0247   0    3      0        8       0
38 0.002130   0.0234   0    3      0        7       0
39 0.001940   0.0221   0    3      0        7       0
40 0.001760   0.0210   0    3      0        7       0
41 0.001610   0.0199   0    3      0        8       0
42 0.001460   0.0188   0    3      0        8       0
43 0.001330   0.0178   0    4      0       10       0
44 0.001210   0.0168   0    4      0       10       0
45 0.001100   0.0159   0    4      0       12       0
46 0.001000   0.0149   0    4      0       12       0
47 0.000914   0.0140   0    4      0       12       0
48 0.000832   0.0132   0    4      0       12       0
49 0.000757   0.0123   0    3      0       13       0
50 0.000689   0.0115   0    2      0       13       0
```